# Bootstrap form-control-file class not working in form

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I am using standart form with botstrap 4.0, all fine but my input button is't apply bootstrap's css.

```
<div class="form-group">                                
 <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you provide more about your code ?

Comment: Iam add devmode screenshoot

Comment: i think that chrome's default styles is override you custom one try to use reset.css and make sure you have include all js files required for bootstrap ( jquery then popper.js then bootstrap.min.js    check this  ( https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't style the button of `input` its type is `file`.

If you want to apply Bootstrap styled file form, you need to use `.custom-file` class.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>Custom File</div>
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="validatedCustomFile" required>
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="validatedCustomFile">Choose file...</label>
</div>
```